# How to make a pop-up (modal) show up right where you clicked on?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm working with a **modal** and I was wondering if anyone knows how to make it show up right where you clicked on and **NOT in the middle of the page**? Basically, if you click on any row of my table you will get a pop-up in the middle of the page, but I want it to show up right where you clicked on.

By default it appends it to the body (middle):

```
 appendTo = "body"
```

Here's my code: [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ubnUKGzf309GtOJOiEui?p=preview)

```
<p-dialog appendTo = "body" header="Title" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="350" height="300">
 {{personData}}
</p-dialog>
```

I also don't want MODAL to go over window when a row is close to the bottom of the window. Please see attached picture:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `positionLeft` and `positionTop` to display your modal where you want.

From the [doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog) :

> positionLeft : Left coordinate value of the dialog.
>
> positionTop : Top coordinate value of the dialog.

---

You just need to tell the coordinates of your cursor when you click on a row. `p-dialog` HTML becomes :

```
<p-dialog appendTo = "body" header="Title" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="350" height="300" positionLeft="{{positionLeft}}" positionTop="{{positionTop}}">
  {{personData}}
</p-dialog>
```

And `onRowSelect` method :

```
onRowSelect(event) {
    this.positionLeft = event.originalEvent.clientX;
    this.positionTop = event.originalEvent.clientY;
    this.display = true;
    this.personData = event.data.name;
}
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oUVEcHi8r4kwRjoSfH1x?p=preview)

Comment: You could just limit it, based on offsets according to the table's positioning. Like: `let x = 151;
      this.positionLeft = event.originalEvent.clientX >= x ? x : event.originalEvent.clientX;`

Comment: @Antikhippe, Thanks a lot bro! It was very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome ! About the overflow problem, you can calculate positionTop like this : `this.positionTop = Math.min(event.originalEvent.clientY, document.documentElement.clientHeight-320);` where 320 depends on the height of the modal. (I edited my Plunker)